# Binding failure with objcopy --redefine-syms

Tags: c++, ld, ld-preload, nm, objcopy

## Preconditions

A third-party has provided a C++ executable `fooapp` that uses a shared object `libfoo.so`. The library also comes with a header `foo.hpp` so developers can build other applications:

```cpp
/* foo.hpp */
namespace foo {
  void bar(int a, int b);
  // More code below here <--- NOTE!!!
}
```

## Success example

This is a standard `LD_PRELOAD`-based function interposition workflow.

First, I write my own version of the library, `myfoo.cpp` that exactly mirrors **part of** `foo.hpp`:

```cpp
/* myfoo.hpp */
# include <ofstream>
namespace foo {
  void bar(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl;
  }
  // NOTHING below here <-- NOTE!!!
}
```

Then I compile my library into `libmyfoo.so` and see the following:

```sh
$ nm libfoo.so -C | fgrep bar
0000000000021fc0 T foo::bar(int, int)
$ nm libmyfoo.so -C | fgrep bar
0000000000010c30 T foo::bar(int, int)
$ LD_DEBUG=bindings LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=ld_debug.log LD_PRELOAD=./libmyfoo.so fooapp
```

**Success!** `ld_debug.log` shows binding as expected, and `bar(...)` generates output to the console.

## Failure example

For the failure example, I'm going to (1) change one character in `myfoo.hpp` and (2) then fix that character in the binary using `objcopy`:

```cpp
/* myfoo.hpp */
# include <ofstream>
namespace foq { // <-- NAME CHANGE!
  void bar(int a, int b) {
    std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl;
  }
  // NOTHING below here <-- NOTE!!!
}
```

When I compile my library into `libmyfoq.so` I see the following:

```sh
$ nm libfoo.so -C | fgrep bar
0000000000021fc0 T foo::bar(int, int) # <-- Sames as before
$ nm libmyfoq.so -C | fgrep bar
0000000000010c30 T foq::bar(int, int) # <-- New name as expected
$ objcopy --redefine-syms=sym.map libmyfoq.so libmyfoo.so # <-- NEW STEP!
$ nm libmyfoo.so -C | fgrep bar
0000000000010c30 T foo::bar(int, int) # <-- SUCCESSful name update
$ LD_DEBUG=bindings LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=ld_debug.log LD_PRELOAD=./libmyfoo.so fooapp
```

**Failure!** `ld_debug.log` shows *NO* binding of `fooapp` symbols to `libmyfoo.so`.

(PS -- If you're curious, `sym.map` contains a mapping between the mangled name of `foq::bar` and the mangled name of `foo::bar`. You can see these if you drop the `-C` from the `nm` command. See `man objcopy` for additional details.)

## WHY?

In summary:

- `objcopy` is renaming the symbol correctly.
- The symbol name hasn't changed size.
- **BUT** the loader is ignoring it at load time.

What's the story here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> WHY? What's the story here?

`objcopy -redefine-syms` will only redefine the debugging symbols in the `.symtab` and `.strtab` symbol tables, not the symbols in the `.dynsym` and `.dynstr` symbol tables that is used for dynamic loading.

If you examine the library you created with `objcopy` with `nm -D` or `readelf -s` you'll see that the name used by the dynamic loader is still `_ZN3foq3barEii`, or with `nm -DC`, `foq::bar(int, int)`.

So, that's what's going on.

The most official references I could find indicating that `objcopy` can't be used to update the dynamic symbols is this unassigned bugzilla entry from 2010:

[Bug 11386 - objcopy should be able to update dynamic symbols visibility](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11386)

And my own query on the official `binutils` mailing list:

[Redefining dynamic symbols](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2019-01/msg00254.html)

---

As a side note, I don't think there's a tool available to redefine the dynamic symbols (properly), but I could be wrong.

The [cjacker/elfhash](https://github.com/cjacker/elfhash) project from 2015 seems to make an attempt. I tried that and it seems to actually rename the dynamic symbol name - but loading the `.so` afterwards fails and the original libs symbol is used instead.

```
% elfhash -f _ZN3foq3barEii -t _ZN3foo3barEii libmyfoq.so
% mv libmyfoq.so libmyfoo.so
% LD_DEBUG=bindings LD_DEBUG_OUTPUT=ld_debug.log LD_PRELOAD=./libmyfoo.so ./fooapp
ERROR: ld.so: object './libmyfoo.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot change memory protections): ignored.
```

Comment: Do you have a citation for the objcopy limitations you mentioned?

Comment: Mostly very old ones like [objcopy --redefine-sym on .dynsym section](http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/objcopy-redefine-sym-on-dynsym-section-td119610.html), but now that you know what's happening, searching for _ELF renaming symbols in the dynamic symbol table_ (or similar) will probably give the all those I found.

Comment: Looks like it's probably the right answer but I'm looking for an official reference to reward the bounty.

Comment: I suspect that's going to be hard. I looked at the source code, [objcopy.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-toolchain/+/vendor-src/binutils/binutils/objcopy.c) and could only find `SHT_SYMTAB` mentioned in there, not `SHT_DYNSYM` that you can find in tools just reading files, like [readelf.c](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-binutils/+/upstream/master/binutils/readelf.c). Perhaps that's a sign that it can't be done with `objcopy`.

Comment: @BrianTheLion I added a link to a query I made on the binutils mailing list. Perhaps someone will give an official statement there some day. I've also cloned the latest and greatest version of binutils/objcopy but haven't found anything in there suggesting it can be done.